# LoadError on line ["51"] when trying compass watch command

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I am new at SASS, but I have been trying to use the "compass watch config.rb" command but when I run it I get:

> LoadError on line ["51"] of /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- animation
>
> Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

Any help that anyone could offer would be great.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the sass and compass gems.

Comment: Are you using stable versions or edge versions?

Comment: I assume that I am using a stable version but I am a newbie so I don't really know what that means.

Comment: You don't want to watch or compile config.rb, the command should just be `compass watch` (or `compass compile`).

Answer (score 6):

I got it going now. Turns out that I needed to install the "animation" gemfile.

```
gem install animation --pre
```

Thanks for everyones help.